# PHP how to divide a variable and then send it to sql

Tags: php, sql, variables

Lets say that i post a value from a form and the input is named date, with the format: ddmmyyyy. I want to divide the variable $_POST['Date'] which is for example 16022009. Into three parts like the first two are separated into one variable and then fourth and third is separated into one variable, you get the idea by now i hope.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What output you want to achieve?

Comment: Hello Sam, welcome to Stack Overflow. Here normally we correct very specific questions or pieces of code. In this case, you are explaining your problem very well but I can´t see what efforts have you did for now, like google this question. [Here you have documentation about substr, but, if you want code you have to put some from your own](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: Nope. Show us your expected result.

Comment: I understand that you have a problem. But, you should try to solve it on your own first. And if you can't get it solved, then put up a question, show what have you tried and didn't worked and then ask to community for help. I guess, that's the best way on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
   $d = 16022009;// $d= $_POST['Date'] ;
   $x = substr($d, 0, 2) .'-'. substr($d, 2,2) .'-'. substr($d,4,4);
   echo $x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
$day = date('d', strtotime($_POST['Date']));
$month = date('m', strtotime($_POST['Date']));
$year = date('Y', strtotime($_POST['Date']));
```